# Adding a metaclass level to the C++ object model

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, metaclass, virtual-destructor, object-model

Could someone explain this theoretical question about the C++ object model? It was on a recent exam of mine and I was stumped by it.

Question:
Noting the success of Java, C#, and Smalltalk, the C++ Standard Committee has decided to add an additional level to the language's object model. Namely, each class should have a meta-class that has a representation at run-time.

1. The opponents says that this contradicts one of the language's fundamental principles. Which? Explain.
2. The opponents have also claimed that C++ has an additional "half-level" that allows some of the functionality of the full-blown metaclass level. What is this "half-level" and what kind of clases enjoy its capabilities?
3. The supporters have come up with a winning argument. Adding a level will provide support for the Mark phase in a Mark & Sweep garbage collection (in which all reachable objects are first marked, and then non-reachable ones are freed). What feature in the additional level does their argument rely on?
4. In addition, the supporters have come up with another argument. The additional level will make virtual destructors redundant, even without a garbage collection system. Explain when and why a virtual destructor is needed and how an additional level will eliminate that requirement?

Comment: Explain which parts? What do you understand and what do you not understand? What would you answer? (If your answer to this is "I have no idea what to answer", explaining this to you would require teaching a considerable amount of C++, and thus make this question way too broad)

Comment: So you were unable to answer this during your exam. Fair enough. But you now have all resources at your disposal, including the full internet. How far did you get in answering these questions yourself?

Comment: Well I actually answered some of this in the exam. I believe question 1) was something about c++ being statically typed, and therefore, metaclass run-time shenanigans would violate that principal. For 2), I answered templates/generics in C++ might provide this "half-level" functionality. Parts 3 and 4 are where I got a bit lost.

Comment: Though the question is slightly beyond SO scope, I kind of would like to read educated and thorough answers. +1. (I also think that you accepted the answer too quickly, it's not as verbose as I have hoped)

Comment: @Dariusz you could ask in the comment and I can try to answer

Comment: sorry guys - but there's nothing about opinions in this question. I know that there is a tendency to put a lot of things on hold but I heartily disagree. The questions will vanish after one or 2 days from the front page anyway, why close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I haven't been in your course, I can only guess:

1: C++ is a kind of lego kit - you take what you need and you can leave everything else. You don't have to pay for it either. Adding this additional level requires some initialization and stuff and I suppose you can't select not to use it - even if you don't require it.

2: RTTI for classes with vtable

3: Here I can only guess - I suppose that all instances of a class are somehow reachable by the meta class or can be detected by scanning the memory. If that's the case, you can implement mark&sweep.

4: virtual destructors are needed if you destroy a class instance via a pointer that has the type of one of the base classes. If you can reach from each instance the meta class, you can then call the correct destructor without the need of having to look it up in the vtable.

Comment: I think you are probably right about 2,3,4. For #1, could it perhaps be that C++ is statically typed and metaclasses violate this? I think your answer for #1 is also correct, just not sure if that is what they were looking for.

Comment: I don't think that metaclasses violate the static typing. They are "only" an enhanced version of the RTTI that already allows the dynamic_cast. Still it's not like in smalltalk where the type is queried at runtime to check whether a method can be called or not.